# Call to undefined method - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, I'm using Laravel 4, I'm trying to create a user controller as the following:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex (){
    }

    public function showProfile($id){

        echo "$id";

        View::make('user.profile');
    }


    public function getNew(){
    }

    public function postNew(){

    }

    public function getLogin(){
    }
```

In the route I want to use: 
     Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

and it's working fine with all expect (showProfile), for example when I go to ../user/profile/2
I get Call to undefined method.

Notice:
I can use

```
Route::get('user', 'UserController@getIndex');
Route::get('user/new', 'UserController@getNew');
Route::post('user/new', 'UserController@postNew');
Route::get('user/login', 'UserController@getLogin');
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

and it will work fine but I don't think it's a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no route you have defined for

```
 ../user/profile/2
```

Have you tried something like:

```
Route::get('user/profile/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

Comment: yes I tried it, however it overwrites all other methods like user/login
but I added something that made it work 
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

so it doesn't overwrite other methods

Comment: but this is still not ideal,what if i wanted to pass {username} instead of {id}, then I can't use where('id', '[0-9]+');

Comment: How does `user/profile/{id}` overwrite other routes? The other routes do not contain "profile" in them

Comment: yeah sorry it works withe /user/profile/{id} or {username}, but I'm actually looking for something like ../user/{username} or more like Facebook ../{username}

Comment: In that case you will need to use a route filter to check whether $username is an actual username stored in your database. http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Comment: this is perfect! the more I dig deeper into Laravel the more I love it, thanks a lot for your help!